# Do all limit-on-close (LOC) and market-on-close (MOC) orders get sent to the stock exchange?

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-exchanges, order-execution

In the US stock market, when I place a limit-on-close (LOC) order or a market-on-close (MOC) order, is the order guaranteed to be executed on the stock exchange? Or are stock brokerage firms allowed to execute these orders off-exchange (e.g. through internalization or through a dealer that provides payment for order flow)? If executed off-exchange, is the execution price guaranteed to be the same as the on-exchange execution price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the order guaranteed (by the broker) to be executed on the stock
> exchange?

Depends on the broker.

> Is the order guaranteed (by the law) to be executed on the stock
> exchange?

No.

> If executed off-exchange, is the execution price guaranteed (by the broker) to be the same as the on-exchange execution price?

No. Such single price auctions are not in the scope of "NBBO or better execution".

> **[17 CFR § 242.611 - Order protection rule (Regulation NMS)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/242.611)**
>
> **(b) Exceptions.**
>
> ...
>
> **(3)** The transaction that constituted the trade-through was a
> single-priced opening, reopening, or closing transaction by the
> trading center.

> **[Definition of "Trading Center"](https://www.sec.gov/spotlight/emsac/memo-rule-611-regulation-nms.pdf)**
>
> Trading center is defined broadly to include all of the types of
> venues that execute trades in today’s equity market structure,
> including registered exchanges, ATSs (both dark pools and ECNs),
> off-exchange market makers, and any other broker-dealers that execute
> trades internally, whether as principal or agent.

Further background available on page 94 of this document:

https://www.sec.gov/rules/final/34-51808.pdf